# Consolidating values on an unevenly spaced spreadsheet Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Writing rudimentary VBA to populate a 2 dimensional array filled with two sums one consisting of the odd columns the other is the sum of the even columns, totaled over a variable amount of rows stored in another array. the two dimensional array then prints on a seperate worksheet. I wrote code which succesfully completed this task on two other worksheets in the same file with slightly different sized arrays, but it populates the destination range with zeros when adjusted for the new input and output.

code in question:

```
Sub dad()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, units As Double, value As Double, mr(1 To 655, 1 To 3) As Double, u As Integer, here As Range
Dim thisone As String, there As Range

thisone = Worksheets("MB52 for 1010").Cells(1, 1).Address
Set here = Range(thisone)
MsgBox (here(1, 1).Address)
thisone = Worksheets("1010totals").Cells(1, 1).Address
Set there = Range(thisone)
MsgBox (there(1, 1).Address)

For i = 1 To 655
mr(i, 1) = Worksheets("1010totals").Cells(i + 1, 4).value
Next i

MsgBox ("array made")
i = 1
u = 1
MsgBox (i & " " & u)
For i = 1 To 655

For j = 1 To mr(i, 1)
    u = u + 1
    units = here(u, 6) + here(u, 9) + here(u, 11).value + here(u, 13) + here(u, 15) + here(u, 17)
    value = here(u, 8) + here(u, 10) + here(u, 12).value + here(u, 14) + here(u, 16) + here(u, 18)
Next j

mr(i, 2) = units
mr(i, 3) = value

Next i

For i = 1 To 655
For j = 2 To 3
    Worksheets("1010totals").Cells(i + 1, j).value = mr(i, j)
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Original code that works on the other worksheets:

```
Sub ded()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, units As Double, value As Double, n As Integer, mr(1 To 756, 1 To 3) As Double, u As Integer, here As Range
Dim thisone As String, there As Range

thisone = Worksheets("MB52 for 1030").Cells(1, 1).Address
Set here = Range(thisone)
MsgBox (here(1, 1).Address)
thisone = Worksheets("1030totals").Cells(1, 1).Address
Set there = Range(thisone)
MsgBox (there(1, 1).Address)

For i = 1 To 756
mr(i, 1) = Worksheets("1030totals").Cells(i + 1, 4).value
Next i

MsgBox ("array made")
i = 1
u = 1
MsgBox (i & " " & u)
For i = 1 To 756

For j = 1 To mr(i, 1)
    u = u + 1
    units = here(u, 6) + here(u, 9) + here(u, 11).value + here(u, 13) + here(u, 15) + here(u, 17)
    value = here(u, 8) + here(u, 10) + here(u, 12).value + here(u, 14) + here(u, 16) + here(u, 18)
Next j

mr(i, 2) = units
mr(i, 3) = value

Next i

For i = 1 To 756
For j = 2 To 3
    Worksheets("1030totals").Cells(i + 1, j).value = mr(i, j)
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```